# Adding cells from one sheet to another based on common cell

Tags: excel

I've tried a few other answers here which seemed similar, but I haven't had any luck yet.

I have two sheets.  The first sheet has two columns: A column with user IDs and a column with user names.  There are several rows that have the same names and user IDs (I can't delete these duplicates).

I have another sheet that has a column with the user IDs and a column with their email addresses.

I need to populate the first sheet with the email addresses that corresponds to the user ID.

In other words, I need to match the same user IDs from both pages and add the email address to the first page.

I hope this makes sense-I tried to create a little table here to better demonstrate it, but the formatting isn't working for me.  I'm not familiar with macros, and I'm hoping to do this in a function.  I tried this one from another answer here and it didn't work for me:

```
=IF($A1=Sheet1!$A1, VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A1, Sheet1!$A1:$D1, 2),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```

Just put the formula in Sheet1 cell C1 and copy it down.

I expect that your user IDs are in Sheet1 Column A and Sheet2 Column A. In Sheet2 Column B there should be emails.

Comment: Has the answer helped?